# Distance and time fields are null in the output of Matrix From Layer algorithm of ORS Tools plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I tried to calculate the travel distance and the travel time using Matrix From Layer algorithm of the ORS Tools plugin in QGIS, but in the attribute table of the output, the duration and distance columns are null.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details of what steps you followed when using the tool.